# TypeError: vis_network__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.DataSet is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, vis.js

I am trying this reactjs. I am getting the following 'not a constructor error'

version used: "vis-network": "^7.4.2",

```
import { Network, DataSet } from "vis-network";

const NODES = new DataSet({});
NODES.add([
  {
    id: "1",
    label: "start",
    final: true,
    x: -184,
    y: -41
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    label: "Node 1",
    final: false,
    x: 11,
    y: -40
  }]);
```

Comment: JavaScript const variables must be assigned a value when they are declared

Answer (score 20):

This is how I resolved the issue. I changed the import statement

```
import { Network } from "vis-network/peer/esm/vis-network";
import { DataSet } from "vis-data/peer/esm/vis-data"
```

I'm going to post the answer found from https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/588

**vis-network** bundles everything, many things multiple times. It throws these and other errors in many circumstances. Don't use it. It will be deprecated and removed eventually.

**vis-network/standalone** bundles everything (polyfills + Vis Data). If you use this you have to use the DataSet exported by this. The downside of this is that it works only on it's own, it will fail when used together with Vis Timeline etc.

**vis-network/peer** bundles polyfills only. You have to use DataSet from vis-data/peer. An advantage here is that it works together with Vis Timeline etc.

**vis-network/esnext** bundles nothing. You have to supply all dependencies yourself and use DataSet from vis-data/esnext. The advantage in this is that you can reuse polyfills and other dependencies from your app, reducing bundle size.

Comment: I found that you could remove everything after the `/esm/vis.*` part. ie. `import { Network } from "vis-network/peer";`. It works for the DataSet import too.

Comment: as of this time if you choose to mirror the examples of visjs for node.js and webpack from npm install vis-network this path seems to work
const vis = require('vis-network/standalone')

wish they would have said that in their doc. The npm / typescript / min legacies stuff in the repo has made it confusing what is what and how it works.