# How can I resolve vis_network__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.DataSet is not a constructor in cjs module?

Tags: vis.js

I've built an internal package on top of `vis.js` that packages itself as both `cjs` and `mjs`. The package runs fine on its own. However, when I import and attempt to use it I get a `vis_network__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.DataSet` error.

I've tried [importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920949/typeerror-vis-network-webpack-imported-module-3-dataset-is-not-a-constructor) DataSet from various subdirs of `vis-network` and `vis-data`. But, I haven't had any luck. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. All I had to do was install `vis-data` separately as opposed to relying on the package installed with `vis-network`.